# Image URL is downloaded as .Zip format

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have used DownloadManager class for image download. When I have used below image url in browser it is working fine. but when i have downloaded that image url using DownloadManager it is getting .zip format.

Image Url : [Here](http://storedge.in/Home/DownloadZip.aspx?storage=PtxIdlnUVjRakf48pN422NjOKPyRI1YCHuwSQVjKXqVySvLCLtMvRt7Q83z/%20HMJYlcNbgdGWbqnzvsKhBe1Qm%20CspbFE/yOpg5nJ2JxlQkbtZnwpEYAosdkSDjzR2cU7%20069lduLMvcwr5JH2sTFdBvom9NDOwWvT1Q1e9sGWitPX/qP1GLpyffBBhWA/i9WDCyAye1mGb4e%20/OeHIAvw%201oCaTHqXDB8JfHAYSwuUorJ/PL/NlsUJlK%20qq/w2tGR1lW9JsA9hUCtoAQgEbHHKIp//v9z3m%20Z2bO4YKQuQ=)

Below is my code of download Manager :

```
private void startDownload(String url) {
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String mimeString = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimeString);
        request.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
        request.setDescription("Downloading " + txtDocName.getText().toString());
        //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg");
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        AppLog.showD(TAG, "downloadind started");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried your request without setting the mimetype?

Comment: I have tried with mimetype too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided URL returns zip as a type. You can check that using any dev tool on your browser as demonstrated in this screen shot
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Comment: can you please share that dev tool so I can explain it my api developer.

Comment: I used Firefox. you can find more details in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox)

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand how is an image of type zip? When I try to download it it just downloads me a jpeg file.

Comment: I don't have the source code for the API part but from I see in the url your address is 'storedge.in/Home/**DownloadZip**.aspx'.. so may be you're adding the type zip to the response.. when you download the file from your browser it ends with .jpg so windows will use your default image launcher so the file will be opened

Comment: one more thing.. in your response headers you have 'Content-Type :application/zip'